# How to deal with extra space characters while Reading a CSV file?

Tags: java, csv

I am reading a CSV file with CSV Open Source API. as shown below:

```
Java Code:-->   

CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(filePath),'\n');
String[] values;
if((read=(reader.readNext()))!=null)            
{                   
    values = (read[0].split(" (?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)",-1)).length;
}

// code ends here
```

When I read this CSV file line by line and split that line with delimiter. Then after spliting values each value I get contains extra space character after each character in String. Suppose value in file is like "ABC" and I got this after reading from CSV file reader as " A B C " . I used removeAll("\s+","") on each value even after it is not working. Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the replace method in the string class for replacing characters, it is an accessor so you need to save the value from it.

try this

```
for(int i =0; i<values.length; i++)
{
    values[i] = values[i].replace(" ","");
}
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: @RaviDutt: are you certain that you are seeing *space* characters and not some other whitespace or control character?

Comment: @user3652871 Actually I have tried replaceAll method as replaceAll("\\s","") and replaceAll(" ","") both are not working.

Comment: @thkala I have mentioned in above comment